# how kibana can create a dashboard which sum the column of some log record

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a request which sum the core and memory of specify jobs, the origin data about core and memory have been put in the elk logs. Like as below picture.

[image]

First red column is core data, the second column is memory data, third red column is job name. Now I want to sum the "core" or "memory" by filtering specify jobs and create a dashboard in kibana. As the dashboard, x-axis is '**time**', y-axis is sum of **'core' or 'memory'**.

I don't know how to sum the column in elk and create dashboard, someone who can help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a scripted field which will add a field at runtime in every document by operations on your current field.

After creating an index pattern , go to that index pattern in settings tab in got to scripted fields tab and a new scripted field.

Name the field which will appear while making the visualisation and add the script as follows.

Here is how to make a script

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/search-request-script-fields.html

And here is a link of how you can do that in kibana

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html